# SWIFT: Trying to decode JSON ,it returns nil

Tags: json, swift, codable

When you i try to call .decode() to decode a struct, it returns nil.Can anyone help me?

My app is returning null value from the JSON data, from this line of code:

```
   let newPosData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewPosDataBase.self, from: responseData)
```

Here is complete code:

```
func getNewLFNREXT(invnr: String, completionHandler: @escaping (String, Bool, NewPosDataBase?) -> Void) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(username: UserCredentials.shared.username, password: UserCredentials.shared.password),
            .accept("application/json")
        ]
        
        let url:String = Config.middleware + Config.url + "/mobile/lfnrext?invnr=\(invnr)"
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: [:], headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                
                do {
                    guard let responseData = response.data else {
                        completionHandler(errorMessage, false, nil )
                        return
                    }
                    
                    let newPosData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewPosDataBase.self, from: responseData)
                    
                    print( newPosData.newPosData?.newLfnrext)
                    completionHandler("", true, newPosData)
                    
                } catch {
                    completionHandler(errorMessage, false , nil )
                }
                
            }else {
                let message = self.getErrorMessageFrom(data: response.data, defaultErrorMessage: errorKeineDaten)
                completionHandler(message, false, nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: You may have an error. Add `print(error)` in the catch block.

Comment: @pawello2222 It does not enter the catch block at all, it returns success but nil

Comment: You have optional variables all over your model. This way you won't have any errors. Try removing them.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include the json response you receive and are trying to decode.

Comment: Why do you even use `responseJSON` when you are parsing the JSON yourself? Ideally, stop using Alamofire framework. It doesn't really bring anything useful anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **`enum CodingKeys`** if the keys' name differ from the property names of the `Codable` type.

So, your models should be like,

```
class NewPosDataBase: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newPosData = "NEW_POS_DATA"
    }
    //rest of the code...
}

class NewPosData: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case newLfnrext = "NEW_LFNREXT"
        case aktuellerZahler = "AKTUELLER_ZAHLER"
        case gpsStd = "GPS_STD"
    }
    //rest of the code...
}
```

**Note:** There is no need to give any `init` implementation in the models unless you need them for any specific purpose.